What is mechanism of the reduction of permanganate ions
How does Permanganate form Manganese 2+ ions in solution when it gets reduced - a specific example being permanganate ions in acidic solution
MnO4- + 8 H+ + 5 e-<----> Mn2+ + 4 H2O
I have seen this reaction - reduction of Permanganate ions but I don't understand how the Permanganate actually forms Mn2+ ions such as in the sense of what bonds are broken. So I am asking if anyone could provide mechanism or just explain how permanganate gets reduced

It's in general pretty much irrelevant how. Afaict you should just know you get aquo complexes of Mn.

But I want to know why permangate converts to Mn2+ in mechanism like mechanisms of hydrogen peroxide decomposititon or of Hydrogen and chlorine radical reaction

Well, we could think of something if you made an edit with specific example.

I have added a specific example

Not specific enough. It depends on reducing agent and pH. Catalyst, temperature... and who knows what else, may be important too.

But there would be many steps involving protonation, binding of reducing agent and water.
